# django rest Error: Missing required positional argument in creating objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have these serializer classes and I'm trying to create doctor and user together

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={'input_type': 'password'}, write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        user = User(
            email=self.validated_data['email'],
            first_name = self.validated_data['first_name'],
            last_name=self.validated_data['last_name'],
            phone_number=self.validated_data['phone_number'],
            social_id=self.validated_data['social_id'],
            gender=self.validated_data['gender']
        )
        password = self.validated_data['password']
        password2 = self.validated_data['password2']

        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password': 'Passwords do not match.'})

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    
class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = '__all__'
        

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        print(user_data)
        
        user = UserSerializer.create(**user_data)
        doctor = Doctor(
            user=user,
            mc_code=self.validated_data['mc_code']
        )
        doctor.save()
        return doctor
```

and I send these json data to these serializers

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "phone_number": "12345678901",
        "social_id": "1234567890",
        "password": "password",
        "password2": "password"
    },
    "mc_code": 123448
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password2'
```

this `create()` is the `create` function for `UserSerializer`
I read docs but I couldn't solve the problem.
What am I doing wrong?

`view` function just in case

```
@api_view(['POST', ])
@permission_classes(())
def doctor_registration_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = DoctorSerializer(data=request.data)
        data = {}
        if serializer.is_valid():
            doctor = serializer.save()
        else:
            data = serializer.errors
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: you need to specify both password and password2 to the serializer. In your code you only specified password but never specified password2

Comment: `password2` is in the `UserSerializer` and `password` is in the `User` model.  also when I use `UserSerializer` separately it works. my code has problem in nested serializers and I think it's in the `DoctorSerializer`